# Why did rep reduction happen today?

Tags: support, reputation

It appears that @hippietrail's and @JoFrhwld's reputation got reduced today (and mine). What caused this reduction?

Comment: This will be addressed by a Community team member soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have checks that detect improper voting.  If this is detected, then a reputation recalc is done.  Looking at user history, I see a rep recalc happened for all three users mentioned in this post.

Comment: what do you mean by improper voting?

Comment: @LouisRhys: Anomalous voting patterns. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/

Comment: This answer is unclear. Are you saying that those who noticed a reduction in reputation were likely voting improperly?

Comment: @Mitch I think the post is mostly referring to sockpuppet accounts that are created just to vote up the main account's posts. I'm pretty sure I don't own any sockpuppet account here, so it might be a mistake in the algorithm or a case of somebody else's sockpuppet which happened to upvote me as well (and since all its votes got cancelled, my rep got affected)

Comment: @Mitch no, the improper votes are removed from the target user and then the target user's rep is recalc'd to adjust the rep to where it should be without the improper votes.

Comment: @Rebecca: so Louis is right? its a third unknown party doing inappropriate upvoting of many people which is then removed?

Comment: Ah so there were people who weren't us who had sockpuppet accounts which voted us up and after discovery of the sockpuppets those votes they had given us were removed and hence our reps recalculated? That sounds like a pretty good reason thanks for clearing it up (-:

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have a different new answer. I think there really is a bug. If I check my reputation tab on my network profile it lists me as having more rep on linguistics than I do here now and also more than I had at the high-point about midnight last night!

Something must be wrong after all.

Comment: The network profile is cached, not live data.

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff: Exactly why it works as proof that the rep was higher at caching time.

Answer (score -1):

<s>Actually mine mostly went up today except for -2 due to a downvote on [my question about alternative analyses of Japanese postpositions as case endings](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/39/are-there-any-papers-etc-analyzing-japanese-as-a-language-with-noun-cases-rather).</s>

It did go down a few days ago though because I put two 100-point bounties on questions. Yes I would've been higher up the "leaderboard" if I hadn't placed several bounties already.

No you're right, I was on `1377` late last night!

Comment: Our SE's area51 page (usually only refreshed once in a while) shows says that your rep is 1,377, me 1,225 and Jo 1,010 and the actual reps are lower now. I didn't put any bounty today or yesterday, and I don't think Jo did either

Comment: Oh yes you're right! I do remember I was on `1377` around midnight last night since it's almost leetspeak for leet! That means mine went down `-75`. Did the others go down by such a round figure do you know?

Comment: I don't know, my rep increased since so I am not sure how much my rep was originally reduced. @JoFrhwld's point was reduced by either 50, 60, or 70 (He gained 2x +10 yesterday, no rep today, and point difference from Area51 is 50 now

Comment: by the way, 1377 is "lett" :P

Comment: Yep "almost leetspeak for leet", but not quite d-;

Comment: Actually, check around if all your questions and answers are still in tact. Around a week ago I noticed one of my answers had been auto-demoted to a comment, which I found a bit rude since there are plenty of other answers here which were further from answering the question than mine. Anyway that could result in rep loss and I don't think there's a notification system for it. If no SE people respond here, try meta.SO but be prepared for greater levels of anal retention (-;

Comment: I don't remember all my questions and answers, lol. Actually I don't really mind, just want to know what the reason was.

Comment: I think there could be a bug or missing feature though so the SE community would benefit from being told your findings I believe.

Comment: Now my rep is leet ;)